# jQuery animate is very choppy in all browsers - div with jpg moving up and fading in at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, fade, fadeto

Or is this the best it's going to get?  I've attempted using script.aculo.us but the fade in and animation of the first image still is choppy.  I've tested in Google Chrome, Safari, and the iPad 1 (veryyy choppy on the iPad 1).  The other elements fade in alright but the first image fadeTo and animate is pretty unacceptable.  Perhaps it's because the divs it moves over are just hidden?

Here's a jsFiddle I've made
http://jsfiddle.net/RgkFc/

and here's the page
http://www.dillon.me/sites/benproudfoot/v1/

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks!

Comment: It works fine for me, just tried in latest FF and Chrome.

Comment: It's pretty smooth for me on my desktop using Chrome 17.

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  It is rather odd - sometimes it looks okay on my end and sometimes looks pretty poor or one bit of choppiness as it moves to the top.  I suppose it's as good as it gets.

Comment: Just to add in case anyone needs help - I was able to smooth out the animate jquery function by delaying it past the fadeTo function.  I believe that having two functions running at once is much more taxing.  Looks pretty great now - www.benproudfoot.com - if anyone wants to check.

Answer (score 3):

The reason why it's very choppy on the iPad (same goes for other iDevices) because jQuery doesn't use the transition hardware, known as transition3d, there is a plugin that support the animations to run the supported transitions [here](http://playground.benbarnett.net/jquery-animate-enhanced/).

Instead you could do it the native way in CSS3, more info:.

- [Keyframe Animation Syntax](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/keyframe-animation-syntax/)
- [Choppy CSS3 animation on iPhone 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5601479/choppy-css3-animation-on-iphone-4)

Comment: "Keyframe Animation Syntax"  is dead :(

Comment: WOW, this is amazing. Fixed all my issues

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but I am also having issues with firefox, I got better results when I removed, CSS tags on the images that were being animated. Note- this wasn't an issue in Chrome